# pdftex.def Error: 'pix/quadratic.pdf' not found : Beamer

Tags: beamer, packages, pdftex, errors

I am using a beamer template to make a presentation. When I compile the code I am getting the following error which I have no idea about.

`<Package pdftex.def Error: File 'pix/quadratic.pdf' not found`

I am not able to figure it out because the preentation looks fine. However, I am not able to ignore these error messages. Should I ignore them or is it something serious? Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using the standard "famous" beamer template "warsaw".

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I had faced the same problem. This morning, I found out that the filename was too long. I changed it shorter.

From:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Pictures/Fig1_Theory_Map1.png}
```

into:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Pictures/Fig1_Theory1.png}
```

It has been solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Read the template before you use it. Perhaps you used an example which includes such a file. A google search for "pix/quadratic.pdf" quickly reveals such examples. Check your document for `\includegraphics` or other commands with such a file name as the argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Stefan. It was indeed the `\includegraphics` command. I should have checked the template. I rather thought there was something wrong with the pdftex.def file. I am new to beamer and tex. Thanks again for helping me out.